# Как перенаправить/записать поток вывода python-скрипта в программе c++/qt?

Tags: python, c++, qt, visual-studio

В программе на c++ вызывается python скрипт посредством:

```html
auto value = PyObject_CallObject(mainFunction, args);
```

**Как поймать/перенаправить отладочный вывод этого скрипта?**

В случае, если выполнить этот скрипт через powershell и python.exe, то отладочный вывод присутствует.

Comment: `sys.stdout = OutputSink()`  где `OutputSink` должен иметь метод `def write(self, message):`